# TextField Change event in a CustomCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, custom-cell

I have been working on CustomCell in `Xamarin.iOS` platform. The following code is working fine. I have tableItems which is List that stores `Start` and `End` values.

And I also have a class(`SettingCustomCell`) where I have programmatically created TextFields to display `Start` and `End` values.

I wonder how could I detect/capture when user changes either `Start` or `End` values in the TextField in my current implementation.

**MainTableViewController**

```
tableItems.Add (new TableItem() {Start=1000, End=4000});
tableItems.Add (new TableItem() {Start=4000, End=6000});

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    SettingsCustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as SettingsCustomCell;

    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new SettingsCustomCell (cellIdentifier);
    }

    cell.UpdateCell (tableItems [indexPath.Row].Start, tableItems [indexPath.Row].End);

    return cell;
}
```

**SettingsCustomCell**

```
public CustomCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
{
    SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

    firstLabel = new UITextField ();
    secondLabel = new UITextField ();

    ContentView.Add (firstLabel);
    ContentView.Add (secondLabel);
}

public void UpdateCell (int caption, int subtitle)
{
    firstLabel.Text = caption.ToString();
    secondLabel.Text = subtitle.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the eventhandler in the tablecell. And when the your UITextField text change call this eventhandler.

   ```
   public EventHandler<bool> EditingChanged;
   //some code here
   firstTextField.ValueChanged += (s, e) => {
        if(EditingChanged!=null)
            EditingChanged(this,true);
   }
   ```
2. Than in your DataSource you subscribe for EditingChanged event and create another eventhandler which will be called when the EditingChanged will be executed.

   ```
     public EventHandler<bool> SourceEditingChanged;
     public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
     {
           SettingsCustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as SettingsCustomCell;

           if (cell == null) {
                 cell = new SettingsCustomCell (cellIdentifier);
           }
          cell.UpdateCell (tableItems [indexPath.Row].Start, tableItems [indexPath.Row].End);

          cell.EditingChanged += {
              if(SourceEditingChanged!=null)
                   SourceEditingChanged(this,true);
          }; 
         return cell;
     }
   ```
3. Subscribe for your SourceEditingChange Event from viewController.

   ```
      MySource.SourceEditingChange += (s,e) =>{
           //Your Code here
      }
   ```